# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE PHP Mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

After struggling with PHPmailer on my website I have yet to reach a solution. First, I was receiving fatal errors from my require() function but changed the path to relative and it worked. Next up, syntax error on line 7. I am not entirely sure why I am receiving an error, can anybody help?

```
<?php
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;

$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php"

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();

$mail->Host = "localhost";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Username = "(myemail)";  // SMTP username

$mail->Password = "(mypassword)"; // SMTP password

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = "(myemail)";

$mail->addAddress('anotheroneofmyemails'); 

// set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

// set email format to HTML
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Customer Inquiry Information:';

$mail->Body = $message;

$mail->AltBody = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the `;` at the end of the `require` line.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now I am back to my original error:
 Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a3785759/public_html/PHPMailer/test1.php on line 4

Comment: @JLTheCapo Where did you put the `PHPMailerAutoload.php` file?

Comment: I put the PHPMailerAutoload.php file in the PHPMailer directory, which is in the public_html directory.

Comment: @JLTheCapo Then you need to move the `test1.php` file one directory up (in `public_html`), or change it to `require "PHPMailerAutoload.php";`, or use an absolute path.

Comment: I moved the test1.php file one directory up; no luck with that. From here, my new code (with absolute path) is:
    require PATH. '/public_html/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
No luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Scratch that!!!! your first suggestion worked. I moved the test1.php file back into the PHPMailer directory, and went with the require "PHPMailerAutoload.php"   and it seems to be working! Message didnt send because message body is empty, but THANK YOU!
EDIT: SMTP connect failed, do you think it is obviously because 000webhost doesn't support SMTP?